# subscribing to angular's specific form control value changes with the method valueChanges but doesn't trigger when the value is removed

Tags: angular

I made a component to add multiple values now I want to listen to a specific form control value, so i used the below  method,

```
this.formGroup.get('venueAmenities').valueChanges.subscribe(
    changes => console.log('venueAmenities has changed:', changes)
);
```

This method is called only if the value is added but not called if the value is removed. The form control value is actually stored with an array. so the method is called whenever a value to this array is added but not called when the value is removed from the array.

Please have a look at the whole code on plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ska8sAVmL0CoUDxOoKmD?p=preview

Comment: Did you forgot to call `this.propagateChange(this.valueOfMultipleSelector);` in `remove` *function*? Works for me: [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KDCdau4GxhrmwIYAVcaL?p=info).

Comment: Thanks. this is working.

Comment: can you post this answer as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the `propagateChange` in your `remove` *function*, as you did in `add`:

```
this.propagateChange(this.valueOfMultipleSelector);
```

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KDCdau4GxhrmwIYAVcaL)

Comment: cab you answer this question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583629/custom-form-controls-value-can-update-with-formgroups-patchvalue-method-but-do?noredirect=1#comment76155649_44583629