# custom form control's value can update with formGroup's patchValue method but doesn't reset

Tags: angular

Our form is decoupled with so many components(custom form control). 
I have a component to add multiple values, This component is used as a form control. This form control can be be updated with

```
this.formGroup.patchValue();
```

but cannot empty its value with,

```
this.formGroup.reset();
```

here is the code in plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/Xd3b0f8q0hn4eiNha367?p=preview
***My question is,***
since "valueOfMultipleSelector: Array" is part of the child component , how its value is updated from parent component by just using this.formGroup.patchValue()?

Comment: I checked the plunker code, on firing ` this.formGroup.reset()` , the  `foodWePrefer` of the `formGroup` is actually set to null so that means the values are removed from the formControl. Now I think you want to remove the elements from the DOM as well , right ?

Comment: this.formGroup.patchValue() can add elements but reset cant remove it. I can only remove using viewchild decorator. what is happening?

Comment: Actually it is removing, check the output `this.formGroup.value` after you fire `reset()`. The `foodWePrefer` is set to `null`

Comment: i'am talking about the values in the dom.

Comment: Did the solution I provided worked for you ?

Comment: I already know, how to empty the array by accessing the child component. My question is how does the form control's value in the dom populated with the patchvalue method? As you can see the value is populated without accessing the child component's. how does it happen? you can also use setter, instead of using ngOnChange.

Answer (score 1):

This is because JavaScript objects are **mutable**. Arrays are "just" objects in JavaScript too, this I mention as a sidenote, since we are dealing with arrays here.

So what does that mean? Shortly said, the `multipleValuesList` is a reference to `foodWePrefer`. So whatever happens to either of these arrays, will affect the other. That is why your child gets automatically "updated" when you use `patchValue()` in parent.

Mutability can be easily demonstrated with `@Input` in child component. If you pass an object from parent to the child, you do not need to have `@Output` in child for the parent to be updated! If you on the other hand have a string, which is not mutable (along with other primitive types), your parent will not know of the changes you make in child. Here's **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dnkp6CeBmaEuqnFUWSnJ?p=preview)** showcasing that.

That JS objects are mutable is important to remember, because it can cause unwanted behavior, when you actually don't want the other variable to be affected when changing the other. Maybe you don't actually want the parent to be affected when modifying the object in the child?

In this case you **do** want that behavior though.

You say the the `form.reset()` doesn't reset the form in child, it actually **does**, you can see when you click the reset button `foodWePrefer` becomes null, which is exactly the behavior we expect from `form.reset()`

But what you mean, is that the items does not get removed from the DOM in child.

**Why?**

That is because those items are stored in a **different** array, i.e `valueOfMultipleSelector`. This array has **no** reference to either `foodWePrefer` nor `multipleValuesList`, so when changes happen in either of these two latter arrays, it does of course not affect the `valueOfMultipleSelector` array at all.

Hope you understand what I'm trying to explain and that you get a better understanding of what is going on in your code :)